# $.ajax POST is not posting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is exactly what the title describes, when I hit submit, and use php file to `echo` the result its empty.

```
$( "form#fileupload" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = $( 'form#fileupload' ).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'create_adgroup.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
      $("#footer").html(returndata);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

and the php is as such:

```
ECHO "PRINT POST: ".print_r($_POST);
echo "le titre: ".$_POST['title'];
```

any suggestions please the alert returns the serialized string and it has all the data and title is one of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture all of the form's data and submit it to a PHP script - jQuery Ajax POST example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/capture-all-of-the-forms-data-and-submit-it-to-a-php-script-jquery-ajax-post)

Comment: To return something from `print_r` use `print_r($_POST, true)`.

Comment: You can't easily do file uploads with Javascript like this.

Comment: its not a file upload ... the id's name was from another upload form. its a regular form no uploading

Comment: Just to make sure: You checked the javascript error console? Did you add an error-function to your script in case an actual error occurred on the ajax request?

Comment: @Dropout that didnt resolve the issue for me sir.

Comment: @ArminHackmann I have firebug open and I do receive the results of the ajax request... it displays random echos and such. but the data sent via POST is not showing

Comment: Please paste the HTML as well, the JavaScript code looks fine. Did you check the console to see of there is a script error? or watch if there is a post happening?

Comment: @ClainDsilva the post does happen. I am using firebug. you see that there are ~15 variables being posted. but when I try to retrieve them on the php file $_POST is empty

Comment: there is an error on your PHP code --> ECHO "PRINT POST: ".print_r($_POST);  is wrong ... just try print_r($_POST); without the "echo " and the string. It should show the post variables ..

Comment: You're probably confusing your webserver with `contentType: false`, bet that's why using the more convenient `$.post` works for you.

Comment: Im looking it up. @mabi thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this, usually i did the ajax POST with this kind of code:

```
$( "form#fileupload" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  $.post('create_adgroup.php', $('form#fileupload').serialize(), function(data) {
    $('#footer').html(data);
  });

  event.preventDefault();  
  return false;
});
```

Comment: The question is not about getting an Ajax method, rather fixing the existing code , which is not limited to Ajax itself. Try to read the questions and comments before posting the answers.

Comment: this actually did work for me thank you Jalansesama! now all the vars are there and work shall continue.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading file using ajax I prefer using jquery.form.js plugin. 
[Reference](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started)